# R plots: simple statistics on data by year. Base package

Tags: r, graph, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

How to apply simple statistics to data and plot them elegantly by year using the R base plotting system and default functions? 
The database is quite heavy, hence do not generate new variables would be preferable.

I hope it is not a silly question, but I am wondering about this problem without finding a specific solution not involving additional packages such as ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate, such as the ones I found on the site:

[ggplot2: Group histogram data by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842008/ggplot2-group-histogram-data-by-year)

[R group by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143510/r-group-by-year)

[Split data by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872790/split-data-by-year)

The use of the R default systems is due to didactic purposes. I think it could be an important training before turn on the more "comfortable" R specific packages.

Consider a simple dataset:

```
> prod_dat

lab      year        production(kg)

1        2010        0.3219
1        2011        0.3222
1        2012        0.3305
2        2010        0.3400
2        2011        0.3310
2        2012        0.3310
3        2010        0.3400
3        2011        0.3403
3        2012        0.3410
```

I would like to plot with an histogram of, let's say, the total production of material during specific years.

```
> hist(sum(prod_dat$production[prod_dat$year == c(2010, 2013)]))
```

Unfortunately, this is my best attempt, and it trow an error:

```
in prod_dat$year == c(2010, 2012):
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I am really out of route, hence any suggestion can turn in use.

Comment: You are doing your subset-selection incorrectly. With multiple arguments in a boolean comparison the argment gets recycled (so year one gets compared to 2010, year two to 2013, year three to 2010 etcetera). Hence the error of about object lengths. You could do `year %in% ....` or `year==a|year==b`.

Comment: `with(prod_dat, hist(production[year %in% c(2010, 2013)]))`

Comment: @Heroka, thanks for your confirm. I was almost sure the problem was that. Do you think that the command implemented with your suggestion (and rawr 's one) may constitute a good solution?  Sorry the sad formatting, I still do not get how to report code parts in comments!                                                                                            hist(sum(prod_dat$production[prod_dat$year %in% c(2010, 2013)]))

Comment: @Worice yes. If you're unsure, you can always check `prod_dat[prod_dat$year %in% c(2010,2013),]` if you've selected the right data.

Comment: I agree. It appears to be a proper solution to the problem. Thank you very much, @Heroka, for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without `ggplot` I used to do it like this but there are smarter way I think

```
all <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = "lab      year        production

                  1        2010        1
                  1        2011        0.3222
                  1        2012        0.3305
                  2        2010        0.3400
                  2        2011        0.3310
                  2        2012        0.3310
                  3        2010        0.3400
                  3        2011        0.3403
                  3        2012        0.3410")




ar <- data.frame(year = unique(all$year), prod = tapply(all$production, list(all$year), FUN = sum))
barplot(ar$prod)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of the selection going wrong/error being thrown.